# How can I avoid ClassCastException being thrown when tree filtering with a custom AST node type?

Tags: java, antlr

I have built an AST using a custom AST node type that derives from CommonTree.

This seems to work ok until I use a tree filtering grammar that contains * wildcards.

The comment on [this](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23232571) page suggests that this is caused by the code having to do:

```
(MyCustomType)input.LT(1);
```

This throws when it encounters an UP or DOWN node as they are of class CommonTree.
The solution in the comment is for optional (?) elements, but I really need a way of using the * wildcard to capture a list of things, without it throwing.

EDIT:

This is a small example that illustrates the problem I have.

The source.txt shows a few examples of what I need to be able to parse.
The problem comes when I went to use a tree walker to rewrite any array assignments(line 3 source.txt) into calls to a *push* function on the array object.

Running the following code with source.txt results in the ClassCastException between node types.

Sccee.g:

```
grammar Sscce;

options
{
    output = AST;
    ASTLabelType = SscceAST;
}

tokens
{
    ASSIGN;
    ARGS;
    FUNCCALL;
    REF;
    INDEXOP;
}


@lexer::header
{ 
package com.dummyco.dummypack;
}

@parser::header 
{ 
package com.dummyco.dummypack;
}

stmts: singleStatement+
    ;

singleStatement
    : memberExpression '=' (expr | listAssignment) ->
    ^(ASSIGN '=' memberExpression expr? listAssignment?)
    ;

expr
    : memberExpression
    | functionCall
    ;

functionCall
    : memberExpression args -> ^(FUNCCALL args)
    ;

args
    : '(' memberExpression? (',' memberExpression)* ')' ->
        ^(ARGS memberExpression*)
    ;

indexSuffix:
    '[' ID? ']' -> ^(INDEXOP ID?)
    ;

memberExpression
    : ID ('.' ID)* indexSuffix? -> ^(REF ID+ indexSuffix?)
    ;

idList
    : memberExpression (',' memberExpression)* -> memberExpression+
    ;

listAssignment
    : '{' idList '}' -> ^(ARGS idList)
    ;

assignmentOperator
    : '=' | '*=' | '/=' | '%=' | '+=' | '-=' | '<<=' | '>>=' | '>>>=' | '&=' | '^=' | '|='
    ;

ID  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_')*emphasized text* ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')* { setText(getText().toLowerCase()); }
    ;

WS  : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

SscceWalker.g:

```
tree grammar SscceWalker;

options
{
    output = AST;
    ASTLabelType = SscceAST;
    tokenVocab = Sscce;
    filter = true;
}

@header
{
    package com.dummyco.dummypack;
}

topdown
    : arrayAssignment
    ;

arrayAssignment
    : ^(ASSIGN '=' ^(REF memexp+=.* INDEXOP) ^(ARGS args+=.*)) ->
        ^(FUNCCALL ^(REF $memexp*) ID["push"] ^(ARGS $args*))
    ;
```

Main.java:

```
package com.dummyco.dummypack;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;

public class Main
{

    private static final TreeAdaptor sscceAdaptor = new CommonTreeAdaptor()
    {
        @Override
        public Object create(Token token)
        {
            return new SscceAST(token);
        }

        @Override
        public Object dupNode(Object t)
        {
            if(t == null)
                return null;

            return create(((SscceAST)t).token);
        }

        @Override
        public Object errorNode(TokenStream input, Token start, Token stop, RecognitionException e)
        {
            return new SscceASTErrorNode(input, start, stop, e);
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        SscceLexer lexer = null;
        try
        {
            lexer = new SscceLexer(
                new ANTLRFileStream("source.txt", "UTF8"));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Can't open the specified file.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        SscceParser parser = new SscceParser(tokens);
        parser.setTreeAdaptor(sscceAdaptor);
        SscceParser.stmts_return r = null;
        try
        {
            r = parser.stmts();
        }
        catch(RecognitionException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Parser exception.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        SscceAST t = (SscceAST)r.getTree();
        CommonTreeNodeStream nodes = new CommonTreeNodeStream(t);
        nodes.setTokenStream(tokens);
        SscceWalker walker = new SscceWalker(nodes);
        walker.setTreeAdaptor(sscceAdaptor);
        t = (SscceAST)walker.downup(t, false);
        System.out.println(t.toStringTree());
    }
}
```

SscceAST.java:

```
package com.dummyco.dummypack;

import org.antlr.runtime.Token;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.Tree;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.CommonTree;

public class SscceAST extends CommonTree
{
    public SscceAST()
    {
        super();
    }

    public SscceAST(Token t)
    {
        super(t);
    }

    public SscceAST(SscceAST tree)
    {
        super(tree);
    }

    @Override
    public Tree dupNode()
    {
        return new SscceAST(this);
    }
}
```

SscceeASTErrorNode.java:

```
package com.dummyco.dummypack;

import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;

public class SscceASTErrorNode extends SscceAST {
        public IntStream input;
        public Token start;
        public Token stop;
        public RecognitionException trappedException;

        public SscceASTErrorNode(TokenStream input, Token start, Token stop,
                                                   RecognitionException e)
        {
                //System.out.println("start: "+start+", stop: "+stop);
                if ( stop==null ||
                         (stop.getTokenIndex() < start.getTokenIndex() &&
                          stop.getType()!=Token.EOF) )
                {
                        // sometimes resync does not consume a token (when LT(1) is
                        // in follow set.  So, stop will be 1 to left to start. adjust.
                        // Also handle case where start is the first token and no token
                        // is consumed during recovery; LT(-1) will return null.
                        stop = start;
                }
                this.input = input;
                this.start = start;
                this.stop = stop;
                this.trappedException = e;
        }

        public boolean isNil() {
                return false;
        }

        public int getType() {
                return Token.INVALID_TOKEN_TYPE;
        }

        public String getText() {
                String badText = null;
                if ( start instanceof Token ) {
                        int i = ((Token)start).getTokenIndex();
                        int j = ((Token)stop).getTokenIndex();
                        if ( ((Token)stop).getType() == Token.EOF ) {
                                j = ((TokenStream)input).size();
                        }
                        badText = ((TokenStream)input).toString(i, j);
                }
                else if ( start instanceof Tree ) {
                        badText = ((TreeNodeStream)input).toString(start, stop);
                }
                else {
                        // people should subclass if they alter the tree type so this
                        // next one is for sure correct.
                        badText = "<unknown>";
                }
                return badText;
        }

        public String toString() {
                if ( trappedException instanceof MissingTokenException ) {
                        return "<missing type: "+
                                   ((MissingTokenException)trappedException).getMissingType()+
                                   ">";
                }
                else if ( trappedException instanceof UnwantedTokenException ) {
                        return "<extraneous: "+
                                   ((UnwantedTokenException)trappedException).getUnexpectedToken()+
                                   ", resync="+getText()+">";
                }
                else if ( trappedException instanceof MismatchedTokenException ) {
                        return "<mismatched token: "+trappedException.token+", resync="+getText()+">";
                }
                else if ( trappedException instanceof NoViableAltException ) {
                        return "<unexpected: "+trappedException.token+
                                   ", resync="+getText()+">";
                }
                return "<error: "+getText()+">";
        }
}
```

source.txt:

```
this.something = this.somecall(someparam, anotherparam)
this.dummy1 = this.dummy2
this.control[]={this.control1, this.control2, this.control3}
```

Comment: Could you post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates a CCE?

Comment: I have been trying to put one together for you, but I can't replicate the problem in the example as I expected. Will keep working on it and post when I get somewhere.

Comment: I have added some code. Sorry it is not wonderfully compact, but I only seemed to be able to demonstrate the problem when I added a little more than the basics in. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks, no matter it's not *that* short. The most important is the copy-paste-and-see-the-problem aspect of an SSCCE. I'll have a look at it later on.

Comment: Alas, I couldn't get it working with a custom `ASTLabelType`. But I must confess that I am rather unfamiliar with ANTLR's *tree pattern rewriting*: I've never used it myself. I usually tend to go with a `CommonTree` and create custom nodes (and possibly do rewrites) either by manually walking the AST, or by using a tree walker on the entire grammar. You could try [the mailing list](http://www.antlr.org/mailman/listinfo/antlr-interest). Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for all your help and time spent on it Bart. This rewrite isn't crucial right now, but I am sure I will have to come back and solve it one way or another soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  `instanceof` operator?  It is used to determine whether a given object is of a certain type and protects against `ClassCastExceptions` being thrown at runtime.

```
Object object = input.LT(1);
if (object instanceof MyCustomType){
   MyCustomType type = (MyCustomType)object;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but the above line appears in generated code. I am really looking for an option or way of specifying the grammar that will avoid the situation.